# Performance Implications of Using Multiple Materials with the Same Texture in a Skinned Mesh Renderer

Tags: unity

I have a skinned mesh renderer that uses seven materials, all of which share the same texture and local in difference body part. Will this setup render seven times, and could it potentially impact performance?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this setup render seven times?

Yes. Each material you put into the materials list will generate a separate draw call. If your mesh is divided into submeshes for each body part, those draw calls will render just that body part, rather than redrawing all faces in the complete mesh.

[You can use the Rendering Statistics overlay to count the draw calls](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingStatistics.html) to investigate questions like this yourself.

> could it potentially impact performance?

Yes. More draw calls tends to lead to increased performance cost. There's a certain amount of overhead to each call, and some cost to switching state to the new material while letting shaders executing the previous material finish their work.

These state switches between draw calls can be relatively inexpensive if you're using the same shader variant just with different material properties, and your project is using a Scriptable Render Pipeline (URP or HDRP) thanks to the [SRP Batcher](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/SRPBatcher.html). On the built-in render pipeline or when changing shaders between materials, the cost is higher.

But what matters most is how this character stacks up against the rest of your scene. Seven draw calls for one main hero character is usually not a serious problem. 7 calls for each tiny pedestrian in a crowd of hundreds could noticeably bog down rendering.

The best way to learn what performance trade-offs are an issue for your game is to use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to measure the impact in an example scene, on your target hardware.